# bad file descriptor fileno

Tags: c, file, operating-system

I am having trouble using fcntl() and fileno. I am having trouble implementing a lock mechanism. However when I try to close a file I get the following error  ***fcntl: Bad file descriptor***. I am using fileno to get the file description and I am getting -1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//args ==path to the file
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct flock lock = {F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET,   0,      0,     0 };
    int fd;
    FILE* fp;

    lock.l_pid = getpid();

    if (argc > 1) 
        lock.l_type = F_RDLCK;

    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    fd=fileno(fp);

    getchar();

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    lock.l_type = F_UNLCK; 


    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should have handled argc <= 1

Answer (score 2):

According to [`fcntl(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fcntl):

> **EBADF**: `fd` is not an open file descriptor, *or the or the command was `F_SETLK` or `F_SETLKW` and the file descriptor open mode doesn't match with the type of lock requested*.

And, it happens that you're *not* setting the `l_type` member of `lock` to `F_WRLCK`, as mandated by the man page above. Thus, just add this line before the first call to `fcntl()` and everything will go fine.

```
lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
```

Answer (score 0):

from fcntl manual page as @KemyLand Pointed above

> EBADF  fd is not an open file descriptor, or the command was F_SETLK
>   or F_SETLKW and the  file  descriptor  open  mode
>                 doesn't match with the type of lock requested.

this probably mean that, the problem is in here

```
fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
```

Though this program seems to be working well with below option but I am finding it hard to explain why it seems to work well with these, something to do with opening logic for sure.

```
fp = fopen(argv[1], "a+");
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
fp = fopen(argv[1], "w+");
```

Comment: The problem is because of if (argc > 1) lock.l_type = F_RDLCK; which does not work with "w". I am putting a read lock but trying to write which do not work together well